# Using a String Outside a Method used to read a WebPage

Tags: android

I am using the following code for reading a WebPage.

```
    private class ReadWebPage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        public String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String s = "";
            for (String url : urls) {  
                DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
                try {
                    HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);               
                    InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent();
                    BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(
                                                         new InputStreamReader(content));
                    String h = "";
                    while ((h = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                        s += h;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return s;
        }
    public void onPostExecute (String result) {
    SendingMessage.setText(result);}
    }
```

I have edited the Code to its original state. To make the question a little less complicated, i want to use the `String result` outside `onPostExecute()` method. I don't want to use `AsyncTask` if possible because i want to perform different tasks with `doInBackground(String...urls)` every time it is called. By writing the whole class again and again (at least three times) complicates my code. I want to be able to use the same class. Is it possible?
I am also using different URL each time.

Comment: Hi, just one quick question: so your version differs from the answerer's is: you only had one activity class that extends `AsyncTask` (basically every code was in one class) and the answerer's differs by extracting the `AsyncTask` code from the activity class? Thanks.

Comment: I do want to use it outside my MainActivity. In fact, i was looking for a method that reduces my code length and hence, ambiguity in code.

Comment: It works now? Could you post your solution so that it could help others as well as me?

Comment: what I am trying to do is create more than one methods in the `public interface TaskResultHandler<TResult>` to return the string obtained via `public class WebPageAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, String>`. All i need now is some sort of condition that will decide to which method the string is to be returned. I might try `indexOf()` in the returning string to decide what to do with it next

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are using AsyncTask class; but, in a wrong syntax specially, doInBackground() method only takes one variable parameter which is passed from task.execute(...) method. From what I understand from your description, you are trying to get the result/output from the AsyncTask class for further processing. Here, below a demo code for what you are trying to do (I just gathered it from some of my projects and should be OK)-

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

//NOTE: Create class/inteface in their own file.

// Implement the handler in a activity and pass the reference
// in the custom AsyncTask constructor
public interface TaskResultHandler<TResult>
{
    public void handleResult(TResult result);
}

public class WebPageAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{
    private TaskResultHandler<String> handler = null;
    private StringBuilder resultBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    public WebPageAsyncTask(TaskResultHandler<String> resultHandler)
    {
        this.handler = resultHandler;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Called in UI thread
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result)
    {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        // Called in UI thread

        if(handler != null && result != null)
        {
            // Pass the result to the activity
            handler.handleResult(result);
        }

        // Clean reference
        handler = null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled(String result)
    {
        // Do not call super

        // Called in UI thread      

        // Result can be null
        if(handler != null && result != null)
        {
            // Pass the result to the activity
            handler.handleResult(result);
        }

        // Clean reference
        handler = null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String ...urls)
    {
        for(String url : urls)
        {
            // Whether the task is cancelled by the activity/other
            if(this.isCancelled())
            {
                break;
            }

            // NOTE: You can use other approach for HTTP operation; but,
            // it is a workable idea.
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            ResponseHandler<String> handler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
            String result = null;

            try 
            { 
                result = client.execute(request, handler);
                resultBuilder.append(result);
            } 
            catch (ClientProtocolException e) 
            {  
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {  
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            {  
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        }

        // Pass the result to UI thread method onPostExecute()
        return resultBuilder.toString();
    }
}

public class SomeActivity extends Activity implements TaskResultHandler<String>
{
    // How to call
    private void getWebPages(String[] urls)
    {
        // Here, [this] is the class that implemented result handler interface.
        WebPageAsyncTask task = new WebPageAsyncTask(this);

        task.execute(urls);
    }

    // Implemented in activity (or other) to handle result
    public void handleResult(String result)
    {
        // Receive result generated by getWebPages() method.
    }   
}
```

It should work for what you intended.

**Edit:** AsyncTask documentation has very good information about how to cancel task if it is needed like activity is being stopped or destroyed etc. So, I updated the code. AsyncTask should be used for task that takes **few seconds**. From my experience, without overriding onCancelled(...) method, when an activity is destroyed before task is completed, onPostExecute(...) receives null result and it is rare. And the passed activity reference will be not be there as the task object will be cleared by GC (better to set null after finished with it). I don't think there should be any memory leak.

**2nd Edit:** Replaced web page URL containing type from URL to String as it works well in this context.

Comment: @Mark002-MAB Hi, this `TResult` should be `T`, right (I am guessing because you're reusing your code)? Second: are you applying MVP here? It looks clean to me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @MARK002-MAB Just curiosity: would `WebPageAsyncTask` continue to hold on to the reference to `SomeActivity` while doing work in the background that causes memory and what would happen if `SomeActivity` gets destroyed but the work (namely: `WebPageAsyncTask`) is still working in the background and calls `handleResult`? Again, thanks.

Comment: Works good. Thanks. Just a few adjustments to make for it to work as per requirement.

Comment: @Unheilig You can use T or TResult; it is your choice. When I write something,  I try to make it reusable if it is common and can be used in the future on similar/different context. I didn't know about MVP here (I heard about Microsoft MVP). I updated my answer and I hope it satisfy your curiosity. Your are welcome.

Comment: You meant TResult is a java Build in type? And, would you know the answers to what I asked in the comments to you above? Thanks.

Comment: @Unheilig TResult/T is just an identifier for generics; nothing built-in. From what I know or from my experience, I answered what you asked in my answer above.

Comment: Thanks for update, I didn't know That we could use anything such as TResult in place of the general T in generics.

Comment: Oh and `URL[]` didn't work for me. I'm going for `URL` instead and am still unable to use a string. Can i use a string by any means? I want to use the string to set the returning condition. `URL.equals()` is not useful enough.

Comment: I think i can use the String as well. it works better for returning condition. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: @user3770134 If you want to use String instead of URL that will contain the page URL, then use it. I used string on my project. In the  end, you are passing string in HttpGet constructor. So, just replace URL with String type.

Comment: @MARK002-MAB yea that worked well. Thank You! I wish i could up-vote it